# Data is not being loaded to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I managed to load data by the snowflake CLI, but I want to automatize this.

From what I read, I can load data using SQL statements (My table is, at the moment, with 1 column: `V VARIANT`) and I'm loading data like this:

```js
order => {
   connection.execute({
   sqlText: `INSERT INTO "xx"."xx"."xx" VALUES(${order})` //Also tried only with the tablename
}
```

But when I query everything from the table, it's empty. Why is that?

Comment: What client/langauge is this? It appears to be JavaScript, but the stored procedures API does not include a `connection` object. Is this Node.js? If so, can you show where the `values` are created?

Comment: Yes, it is NodeJS. The connection is already declared and I know it's connected because the `conn.isUp()` method returns me `true`. What do you want me to show you, what values?

Comment: About the connection object, I followed [this documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#executing-statements)

Comment: Can you check the query history in Snowflake after you executed your code to see what queries were executed and did they succeed? What is the value for {$order}? Is it string representation of JSON data?

Comment: Hey Eric, actually, I did solve this. I had to set the database and the schema in the connection. And no, `${order}` was a JavaScript object, so did `JSON.stringify()` to that object and loaded correctly! :)

Comment: @SergioRamirez then delete your question please , thank you